# Excel formula not working - SEARCH(OR(XX;YY)

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formula

I have tried to also search for ("Banana";"Orange"), yet I added OR it does not get the right result for Banana, and Orange.

ORIGINAL CODE, OK!:

```
=IFERROR(IF(AND([@[Country]]="Argentina";ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Apple");[@[Fields]])));"ArgentinaField";VLOOKUP([@[Country]];Table1;2;0));[@Table4])
```

NOT SEARCHING FOR BANANA, AND ORANGE:

```
=IFERROR(IF(AND([@[Country]]="Argentina";ISNUMBER(SEARCH(OR("Apple";"Banana";"Orange");[@[Fields]])));"ArgentinaField";VLOOKUP([@[Country]];Table1;2;0));[@Table4])
```

OR does not work in this case? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Your Formula Syntax is wrong, especially with Search command. What I assume that you have list of County and Fruits and you want to search Fruit name for the Country. 
Suppose your country name is Col 1 & Fruit is in Col 2. 
Write this one, 
=IfError (VLOOKUP (A2, B4:C10, {1,2},False), "") 
Finish this formula with Ctrl +Shift +Enter then you get Country name, then select the Formula cell press Shift +Right arrow ➡ select nXt cell, press F2 and again press Ctrl +Shift +Enter,, now u get its Fruit name.

NB : WRITE COUNTRY NAME IN A2. ☺

Comment: is it not possible to add OR to the command? I mean, the formula `=IFERROR(IF(AND([@[Country]]="Argentina";ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Apple");[@[Fields]])));"ArgentinaField"`is working perfectly. I would like to know how to add one more field into the search. I would like to find multiple text in the cell, not want to vlookup them. Thank you

Comment: My dear friend Search or Find only Returns the Position of data in term of Number only, ☺